# How to get all dialer events from Asterisk REST API (ARI)?

Tags: asterisk, voip, asteriskami

I'm making a web application which should be able to monitor calls on my Asterisk server. I can connect to ARI with Javascript WebSocket on URL `ws://(host):8088/ari/events?app=dialer` and it works. The problem is that I only get events from calls that are made over ARI. Calls made from other clients like Zoiper are not registered. On the other hand, Asterisk has AJAM which uses long polling on `http://(host):8088/rawman?action=waitevent` and it registers calls from all the clients, (ARI, Zoiper and others) but there's only information **who** is calling (caller), not **whom** (callee).

So, my question is, how can I get real time call events that show who is calling who, from all the clients, (preferably) with WebSockets. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ARI uses a subscription based model for events. Quoting from the documentation on the [wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Introduction+to+ARI+and+Channels):

> Resources in Asterisk do not, by default, send events about themselves to a connected ARI application. In order to get events about resources, one of three things must occur:
>
> 1. The resource must be a channel that entered into a Stasis dialplan application. A subscription is implicitly created in this case. The
>      subscription is implicitly destroyed when the channel leaves the
>      Stasis dialplan application.
> 2. While a channel is in a Stasis dialplan application, the channel may interact with other resources - such as a bridge. While channels
>      interact with the resource, a subscription is made to that resource.
>      When no more channels in a Stasis dialplan application are interacting
>      with the resource, the implicit subscription is destroyed.
> 3. At any time, an ARI application may make a subscription to a resource in Asterisk through application operations. While that
>      resource exists, the ARI application owns the subscription.

So, the reason you get events about a channel over your ARI WebSocket is because it went into the Stasis dialplan application. That isn't, however, the only way to get events.

If you're interested in events from other event sources, you can subscribe to those resources using the [applications](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Applications+REST+API#Asterisk13ApplicationsRESTAPI-subscribe) resource. For example, if I wanted to receive all events that were in relation to PJSIP endpoint "Alice", I would subscribe using the following:

```
POST https://localhost:8080/ari/applications/my_app/subscription?eventSource=endpoint:PJSIP%2FAlice
```

Note that subscriptions to endpoints implicitly subscribe you to all channels that are created for that endpoint. If you want to subscribe to all endpoints of a particular technology, you can also subscribe to the resource itself:

```
POST https://localhost:8080/ari/applications/my_app/subscription?eventSource=endpoint:PJSIP
```

Comment: I subscribed to the PJSIP, and now it appears under "endpoint_ids" of that application. "Note that subscriptions to endpoints implicitly subscribe you to all channels", it seems doesn't receive "ChannelDtmfReceived" related to the channels.

Answer (score 6):

ws://(host):8088/ari/events?app=dialer&subscibeAll=true
Adding SubscribeAll=true make what you want =)

Comment: This is a correct answer because otherwise you will get duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

For more clarity regarding what Matt Jordan has already provided, here's an example of doing what he suggests with [ari-py](https://github.com/asterisk/ari-py):

```
import ari
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
client = ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'username', 'password')
postRequest=client.applications.subscribe(applicationName=["NameOfAppThatWillReapThisEvent-ThisAppShouldBeRunning"], eventSource="endpoint:PJSIP/alice")

print postRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

May be help someone:

Subscribe to all events on channels, bridge and endpoints

```
POST http://localhost:8088/ari/applications/appName/subscription?api_key=user:password&eventSource=channel:,bridge:,endpoint:
```

Unsubscribe

```
DELETE http://localhost:8088/ari/applications/appName/subscription?api_key=user:password&eventSource=channel:__AST_CHANNEL_ALL_TOPIC,bridge:__AST_BRIDGE_ALL_TOPIC,endpoint:__AST_ENDPOINT_ALL_TOPIC
```